# How to get list of items with exactly one duplicate in Perl?

Tags: perl

I have a list of strings and I need to remove all items that are unique or has more than one duplicate. Other words, I need **just those** items, **that are in the list exactly twice**. How can I do it in **Perl**?

Comment: @Zaid :: I coded it using hash, to find how many times each item is in the array, ... but I believe it is not the best way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a special case of the classic remove duplicates recipe. When your items are strings, this is really easy in Perl 5:

```
my %seen;
for my $item (@list) {
    $seen{$item}++;
}

my @twice = grep { $seen{$_} == 2 } keys(%seen);
```

It's O(N) on the size of the list, but I don't think you can get away with doing this kind of thing without looking at every element at least once...

Comment: Actually the solution is 2 * N. One pass to count, another for the `grep`

Comment: @stackoverflow the test grep's doing (hash lookup and numeric comparison) is extremely quick, so I don't think performance is going to be a problem here. Anything you might implement yourself using a loop isn't going to be any quicker.

Comment: You can eliminate the second pass by keeping another hash %twos: something like: if($seen{$item}==2) { $twos{$item}++ } else { delete $twos{$item}; }  ... then keys(%twos) is your answer.  This is more cycles, but  might be faster for very large hashes with very small answer sets due to cache effects.